# AS400 Physical File Record Last Updated Timestamp

Tags: ibm-midrange, database-trigger, rpgle

I am trying to add a last updated timestamp to an old physical file on an AS400. This physical file is written in DDS. I have added in the timestamp field but I cannot get it to automatically update to the current timestamp when the record gets modified.

I have tried creating an RPGLE trigger program which sets the timestamp of the field in the after image of the trigger buffer. However this change is not reflected in the actual file since I believe the trigger buffer is an input-only reference.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can get a timestamp on each record that automatically updates when a change is made to that record?

Thank you!

EDIT: I have posted the code that should handle the timestamp update in the trigger program. Am I not getting the trigger buffer set correctly?

```
 d PGMNAME         pr
 d  TrgBuffer_                         like(TrgBuffer)
 d  TrgBufLen_                         like(TrgBufLen)

 d BefImg        e ds                  extname(FILENAME) prefix(b_)
 d AftImg        e ds                  extname(FILENAME) prefix(a_)

 d FILENAMER       pi
 d  p$TrgBuffer                        like(TrgBuffer)
 d  p$TrgBufLen                        like(TrgBufLen)

    TrgBuffer = p$TrgBuffer;
    TrgBufLen = p$TrgBufLen;

    NRO = NewRecOff + 1;
    NRL = NewRecLen;
    ORO = OrgRecOff + 1;
    ORL = OrgRecLen;

    // Set Before / After Images
    BefImg = %subst(TrgBuffer:ORO:ORL);
    AftImg = %subst(TrgBuffer:NRO:NRL);

    select;

    // Update
     when TrgEvent = '3';

     // Set last updated timestamp on record.
     a_lstupd = %timestamp();
     %subst(TrgBuffer:NRO:NRL) = AftImg;
     p$TrgBuffer = TrgBuffer;
```

Comment: On an insert to update trigger, you have to update the after image for your changes to take. The trigger buffer is not a read-only reference. There are other considerations if you are using an ILE language for the trigger program.

Comment: Can you post the trigger program you created?

Comment: Can you convert the physical file to DDL?

Comment: I have added the code for my trigger program. Am I getting the buffer reset correctly? The change shows up in the buffer when I debug but the actual file remains unchanged after the program runs. Switching this to DDL is not an option for this case.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to stick with DDS.

You can use iNav or the newer ACS Schema's tooling to generate SQL DDL for an PF originally defined with DDS.

Then it's a simple matter to add

```
LAST_UPDATED for column LSTUPD
  timestamp not null
  generated always 
  for each row on update 
  as row change timestamp
```

For that matter,  you can use the SQL `ALTER TABLE` statement to add the column to the existing PF.

There's very little difference between a DDS PF and an SQL table at the OS object level.  And what the differences there are, are internal, not external to anything that uses it.

Comment: I can't seem to just add a row change column to an existing table.

Comment: @danny117 sorry, forgot `ON UPDATE`, answer has been corrected

Comment: I did not write the original file and converting it to DDL isn't an option for this particular file. I have added the code for my trigger program. Am I resetting the after image correctly?

Comment: you'd need a BEFORE trigger to change what gets written to the file.  Not an AFTER.